# Citation Undefined and Reference Page Doesn't Print

Tags: biblatex

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours I have looked at many archived posts but the problem keeps continuing. tex. and bib. file are in the same directory and it is seen on TexMaker, there are no typos, miktex is updated (there is no change before and after the update).

I had written a paper months ago with this exact code and it worked but now with the same code it doesn't. I copied the working project and tried just to make changes on writings although everyhting was same it still didn't work. I then updated miktex thinking that may be the problem but still no change. I tried various formats of bibliography setups but still the same error continues.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{abstract}
 \usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=numeric,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bach}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}


\title{title}
\date{2021}
\author{name}

\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}
\maketitle
\section{1}
```

...

```
\cite{boyd}

\clearpage
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@book{boyd,
  author = {Malcolm Boyd},
  year = {1994},
  title = {Bach},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you tried changing `\addbibresource{Bach}` to `\addbibresource{Bach.bib}`?

Comment: @Mico Yes I have tried and it didn't work either. The thing is when I write the command for cite it even shows "boyd" for autofill, it recognises it but the result is as I said.

Comment: You may want to double-check what's wrong about your work flow, then, because your code works just fine for me. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Run `pdflatex` twice, then `bibtex` then `pdflatex` twice.  `bibtex `shoud finish with `Process exited normally`. Of course remember to use `\addbibresource{Bach.bib}`.

Comment: @SimonDispa Oh wow, it worked like magic! Thank you!!!

Comment: @SimonDispa - You shouldn't have to run pdflatex *twice* before running BibTeX. A single pdflatex run should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Your code generates a suitably formatted bib entry and a numeric-style citation call-out as long as I change `\addbibresource{Bach}` to `\addbibresource{Bach.bib}`. (Of course, this assumes that your bib file is named `Bach.bib`. If that's not the case, all bets are off.) Naturally, you have to run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

[image]

Incidentally, the line `address = {Massachusetts},` looks suspect. For US addresses, one always provides both the city and the state, not just the state. This is true even for "Washington, DC", where the whole "state" (technically, it's a territory, not a state...) consists of a single city, *viz.*, Washington. Do try to find out which city in Massachusetts ought to be used.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Bach.bib}
@book{boyd,
  author = {Malcolm Boyd},
  year = {1994},
  title = {Bach},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bach.bib}

\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\cite{boyd}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```